# How can one check whether my Windows 7 supports TLS 1.2?

Tags: windows-7, security, tls

I read on https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/eol-tls-support.html#win7 ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20211125231014/https://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/eol-tls-support.html#win7), [mirror 2](https://archive.ph/adzkN)):

> Your operating system and application frameworks must also support TLS 1.2. If

How can I check whether my Windows 7 supports TLS 1.2? I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 definitely supports TLS 1.2 .  I have a Windows 7 Pro machine here and TLS 1.2 is enabled.

To Check:

Control Panel, Internet Options, Advanced.

Scroll down most of the way to the bottom for TLS and, most likely, all have been enabled. If not, enable, close out and restart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the reg key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled` is 1.

   [image]
2. Make sure that the `kb3140245` Windows update is installed:

   [image]